# How can I set the file name if I run cpp (GNU C preprocessor) from stdin?

Tags: gcc, stdin, c-preprocessor

I have a vague memory of that `gcc` used to pipe the source code through external preprocessor, compiler (proper) and assembler (which no longer seem to be done). Due to this I expect it to be possible to (still) set the filename for the `cpp` even if you preprocess from `stdin`. However I didn't find any such option in the manual.

Note that this matters as first the `__FILE__` macro should expand to the current filename (by default `"<stdin>"`), second the preprocessor inserts line directives in the output containing the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not an command line argument, you could prepend the `stdin` with a line directive (ie a `# 1 "<desired-filename>"` line). Thereby the preprocessor will be told that the line after this is the first line of the desired filename.

Comment: If you want the line numbers to be correct, use `#line 1 "filename"`. The directive tells the preprocessor what the line number of the *next* line is. (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/cpp/Line-Control.html)